# How to kill program running in background in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm working on MINI2440 and building a custom OS for it using buildroot, but for testing purpose I'm using OS downloaded from official website.
So the problem is, I'm using **usbpush** to push OS images in MINI2440 through USB, but it popups the message when I enter below commond

```
sudo ./usbpush supervivi-128M 0x30008000
```

> Unable to claim usb interface 1 of device: could not claim interface 0: Device or resource busy

I don't understand one concept that, whenever I assign executable permission to **usbpush**, it runs automatically in background. It's clearly seen below

```
ps -ef | grep usb*
```

> silicod+  2431  2207  0 10:25 pts/10   00:00:00 grep --color=auto usbpush

I tried to kill using

```
sudo kill -9 2431
```

But it creates new pid and again run itsellf in background. I tried googling but nothing works for me.

=============================================================

Well, I got my solution. I don't know what is the problem with my usbpush tool, but I downloaded another tool and it works very well. Here is the link to that tool , may it help someone 
[Friendly_ARM_Mini2440_USBPUSH](https://github.com/luciano-sabenca/Friendly_ARM_Mini2440_USBPUSH.git)

Cheers....!

Answer (score 1):

lovely ;-)

well I guess it is actually not running..

ps -ef   will give you details about all running processes
grep usb* - (loose the *) will find any lines containing usb

the way unix/linux does it is that grep gets started first and then the "|" connects output of ps -ef to grep's input
so what you are finding is the grep command itself

what you want is ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep usb - this will work unless your "usb" command is something like grepusb or usbgrep or the line contains grep..